# Loadrunner Load Generator on windows XP

Tags: loadrunner

Client wants to use a stack of windows XP machines as load generators to test scripts I'm developing in Loadrunner 12.01 using web\http & Oracle Web App 11i protocals. 
HP's PAM for 12.1 doesnt list Windows XP compatibility for any components, I roughly remember XP Professional edition SP3 was supported by the Load Generator bundled in loadrunner 11.52 but not sure

Will the Load Generator bundled with loadrunner 12.01 work on an XP machine ?
and are there any gotchas ?

NB: XP is stipulated by the client, The scenario will be on our PC instance and we will be talking over SSL on 443 using MI listener. Its just the LG they want to be XP.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't even something we test, considering XP support status with Microsoft. That said, the 12.01 installer will likely fail due to OS checks.

If you were to use version 11.5x load generators with a later version of scripts and scenarios, we can't guarantee it will work as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to use an unsupported operating system in your test bed, which should be solid, stable and beyond question?  You are only arming people who do not like your results with aluminum baseball bats with which to bash them and impugn their value, "Look, they are not even running the tests on supported operating system, we can't possibly trust the results of testing like that..."

Comment: Same argument I made. But like I said - "XP is stipulated by the client", They  are migrating off XP, this bit of testing is for a web app they will be accesing from the remaining xp desktops. They want to use the now huge pile of xp desktops they have to run the LG.  I know ... I wasn't asking if it was a good idea - Just wanted to get a handle on the pitfalls & gotchas. NB PAM for 11.52 does include XP SP3. But I'm hoping to talk them out of it because their version of IE &  jre isnt supported (Again .. I know - but ammo is ammo!)

Comment: Using anything "not supported" is a general bad idea in a test bed.  With the question mark over the app, you don't need a similar question mark over the quality and influence of the testing tool.  It just provides people who don't like your result a reason to walk away and a reason for management to label the effort as "low value for the expenditure..."